SF story set in an isolated (extragalactic) star system
I'm trying to remember a book with a conceit that struck me deeply but that I'm now realizing I remember almost nothing about. The conceit in question is that the setting of the story is a star system that's so impossibly far away from any other star that while the civilization has achieved space travel and colonized its system pretty thoroughly it has no hope whatsoever of ever going further (no such thing as FTL), and has basically resigned itself to stagnation.
I can't even remember how important that theme was to the story even though it's all I remember about it. Plot-wise it almost certainly was nothing more than a fact of the background, it wasn't a "main characters are involved in changing this situation" kind of theme. More of a "this reality subtly but oppressively permeates everything" thing.
I can't really remember anything else. I'm pretty sure the action occurred over several planets and a little bit in space. I'm pretty sure there were several important characters but can't remember if it was an ensemble cast or a main protagonist with friends. I can't remember if it happened over a long span of time with characters growing older or if it was a short adventure. I think the core plot element might have been a heist or treasure hunt? If it was the latter then I feel the "treasure" would have been some archeological find in space.
It might have been part of the series set in that world but I only read that one book in it if so. I remember it as a full-length novel but I wouldn't be shocked if it turned out to be a short story or novelette, given the description.
I think I must have read this between twenty and five years ago and I remember it as not recent but also not strikingly old so I'd guess it's from somewhere between 1990 and 2015?
It doesn't seem to be Orphan Star from Alan Dean Foster.

It's also not World Without Stars by Poul Anderson.

This really feels like Banks' Against a Dark Background which featured the hunt for the "Lazy Gun."
Quoting from the plot summary on Wikipedia:

The main protagonist is Lady Sharrow, a former military pilot and antiquities thief. She lives on Golter, a planet orbiting a star in an isolated planetary system with no nearby galaxies. A cult named the Huhsz is granted permission to assassinate her, believing that their messiah can not be born until the end of her family's female bloodline. She is forced to choose between going into hiding for a year or recovering the last Lazy Gun, an ancient weapon of mass destruction that was stolen from the cult by her ancestor.
Sharrow resolves to recover the Lazy Gun, rejecting an offer of help from her cousin Geis, a wealthy industrialist and businessman. In order to do this, she must first find the Universal Principles, a long lost book rumoured to contain a clue to the Gun's hiding place. She visits her half-sister Breyghun who is held prisoner in the Seahouse, a monastery run by the Sad Brothers. Breyghun tells her that their grandfather Gorko, a collector of rare artefacts, encoded information regarding the location of the Universal Principles into the DNA of his servants. Sharrow recruits the surviving members of her combat unit and sets out to make contact with the son of Gorko's butler. During these events, Sharrow is menaced by two unidentified bald-headed clones, who have the ability to inflict pain on her via a military virus embedded in her nervous system. They demand the Gun be turned over to them and not the Huhsz.


